# Resources to study the cell as a "mechanism"

Tags: cell-biology

I am looking resources that effectively describe the cell as a mechanism. The cell might be irreducibly complex, but the individual components *must* necessarily have simple functions, locks, keys, switches, gears, membranes, and extruders. Is there any resource that exists that classifies the great many substances in the cell in this manner?

Comment: The basic cell biology textbook does explain different parts of the cell. Can you please clarify your question?

Comment: The cell is *not* "irreducibly complex" at all. What makes you think it is? As @WYSIWYG suggested, you should read up on the field of "Cell Biology".